# Is there an another way of saying young people

Tags: synonyms

Like if you want to say old people, you can also say senior and older?
How about young people?

Comment: senior and older are adjectives.  "Seniors" (AmE) or "senior citizens" (AmE) and "the elderly" (pl) are the nouns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the definitions of **youth** is

> **youth**
>
> 6. young persons collectively.

source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/youths)

You can also use **young** as a noun:

> **young**, n.
>
> those who have youth; young persons collectively:
>   *the educated young of today; a game for young and old.*

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/young)

And finally (if the people you want to talk about can be put into these categories) you can also use: *children*, *adolescents*, or *young adults*